# trasfering value from php to javascript inconsistent

Tags: javascript, php

my php code has a value of 2 digits like

```
 $var1 = 16; 
 $var2 = 24;
 $var3 = 31;
```

but when i used those value and put it in my javascript like for example

```
var var1 = <?php echo $var1; ?>
var var2 = <?php echo $var2; ?>
var var3 = <?php echo $var3; ?>

console.log(var1+"-"+var2+"-"+var3)
```

the output is `**1-2-3**` instead of `**16-24-31**` it only get the first digit i even put  `window.onload`function to make sure to load the php and html first before the script.

Comment: *i even put `window.onload` function to make sure to load the php and html first before the script.* <-- this is EPIC.

Comment: If you view the source of the page, do the same (1-2-3) values show up in the `var var1 = etc..` part of the code?

Comment: *'to make sure to load the php and html first before the script'* - PHP executes on the server, upon page request: **always** before the return javascript

Comment: What source does it generate? Also, I can't imagine there would be `*` characters in your output.

Comment: not clear from your snippet, but it looks like you are missing semicolons

Comment: View the source code JavaScript and tell us what those variables look like.

Comment: @Elen: [ASI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: the value i get from the source code is the same in php

Comment: try typecasting as an integer, e.g. `var var1 = <?php echo (int)$var1; ?>` you might need to do this in the javascript too but I am unsure how - maybe declare `int` instead of `var`?

Comment: @Jon his statement reads like: `var var1 = var var2 = var var3 =` - if php echo's nothing

Comment: @verbumSapienti JavaScript is a dynamic language, there are no implicit casting operations available as in C#, and the variables **have to be declared using var**(there are no types like *int*, *string*, etc).

Comment: @Elen: Why on earth would PHP echo nothing? Is there a good reason to make this assumption?

Comment: @Jon yes always check your variables.

Comment: @Elen it is not as you said, otherwise the compiler would have thrown an exception. Follow the link Jon provided you, in JS semicolons are a messy problem.

Comment: is there any factor that white spaces in php may causes the problem because some variable has white space?

Comment: @Elen: I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. The variables are definitely assigned in the example, *and* even if they were not there's no chance the output would be 1-2-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a result of two things:

1. You are not ending your JS statements with semicolons.
2. PHP [eats up *one* newline character if it follows the closing tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) `?>`.

This means that your JS code ends up being something like

```
var var1 = 16var var2 = 24var3 = 31
```

which is not what you expect (actually the above is a syntax error; if the code compiles in your case it might be a result of the example being not identical to the code that runs).

The proper solution is to terminate each statement with a semicolon:

```
var var1 = <?php echo $var1; ?>;
var var2 = <?php echo $var2; ?>;
var var3 = <?php echo $var3; ?>;
```

What would also *work* (although I recommend to avoid it) is to put some extra newlines after each assignment and let [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) take over:

```
var var1 = <?php echo $var1; ?>

var var2 = <?php echo $var2; ?>

var var3 = <?php echo $var3; ?>
```

As an aside, straight `echo` of the variables works in this case because they are numeric. In general, the proper way to transfer variables to JS is through `json_encode`:

```
var var1 = <?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>;
```

Comment: this solve the problem as using json_encode to output the variable even if it has white spaces thank you for this

Comment: @DevfaR: But your example variables don't contain whitespace. Why?

Answer (score 0):

try this : It worked for me

```
<?php

 $var1 = 16; 
 $var2 = 24;
 $var3 = 31;

?>
<script>
var var1 = <?php echo $var1; ?>;
var var2 = <?php echo $var2; ?>;
var var3 = <?php echo $var3; ?>;

alert(var1+"-"+var2+"-"+var3);
console.log(var1+"-"+var2+"-"+var3);
</script>
```

Comment: well it's the same problem i encounter